# Calling routine is not waiting for Google Picker

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-picker

I am trying to use Google Picker to pick a folder and return the folderId. I am able to get the folder id, and even paste it into a spreadsheet cell (which I don't want to do; I just want to use the value in my calling code).  But my calling code zips ahead and doesn't wait for the result of picker. I can see the values on my sheet getting updated, even before I've picked the folder. I used code in this post and slightly modified it. [Google Picker - Return the File ID to my Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074352/google-picker-return-the-file-id-to-my-google-script)

I added 'PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('mykey', fileId);' to save the fileId and 'var myvalue = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('mykey');' in the calling routine to retrieve it.  This works, but the timing is off.

What can make my code sit and wait for the picker output?

I created this function to try and run the whole thing; it is where the code is zipping ahead.

```
function allIn() {
  showPicker() ;
  console.log("Ready to get myKey");           

  var myvalue = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('mykey');    
  console.log("Ready to console log myKey"); //doesn't show this;
  console.log("MyValue returned = " + myvalue); //doesn't show this;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a4').setValue(myvalue); //runs this before picker completes;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359158/waiting-for-async-request-to-return-before-proceeding-google-apps-script looks like it might help using a callback as a parameter but I don't understand what is going on - using a function as an input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a callback function to your [Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#picker) object with the `setCallback(function(object))` method and then use the callback function to do the actions you want after an action is taken on Google Picker like selecting a folder. For example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs#display-the-google-picker) you can create the Picker like this:

```
function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
          addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
          setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
          setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
          setCallback(pickerCallback).
          build();
      picker.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
}
```

The `pickerCallback` would be the name of the callback function to be run after an action is taken on Google Picker, ant it could be defined as this for example:

```
function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = 'nothing';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
      url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
    }
    var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
}
```

All the above code would be placed in the html/JS part of the code. If you want to run some function from Apps Script, you can use the above callback function to make a call to an Apps Script function using [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myfunction...-any-server-side-function), the below line would call the `yourAppsScriptFunction` function from Apps Script side:

```
  google.script.run.yourAppsScriptFunction();
```

You can check the [client-server communication guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) for more explanation.

Comment: Andres - I've been slammed as of late and haven't been able to get back to this.  Hope to check it out shortly.  Brian